# Errors Installing PIL on Mac OS Tiger

Tags: python, macos, osx-tiger

I'm trying to install the Python Imaging Library on Mac OS X 10.4, but I get errors. I'm not sure where the error starts, it's just a huge wall of text when executing `sudo python setup.py install`.

But the last few lines are:

```
...
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
lipo: can't open input file: /var/tmp//ccNKvQpP.out (No such file or directory)
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I've googled, but none of the results are working.

Comment: You should post the whole message.  That just shows the linker failed, which doesn't tell us the root cause of the error.

Comment: `sudo port install py-pil` Macports will save you tons of time :-)

Comment: ok I've tried installing through Macports, but it seems to be installing Python 2.4 also.. I don't want that. (It's still installing now, will see later if it is indeed installing 2.4)

EDIT: turns out there's a py26-pil package. :) Thanks!

EDIT2: how do I remove the files from the cancelled 2.4 install attempt?

Answer (score 0):

It is a good idea to install the [Fink package manager](http://www.finkproject.org/), if you have not yet done so: you have a single point entry to many open-source packages; they have been configured to as to be precisely adapted to Mac OS X.

Once you have installed Fink, a simple

```
fink install pil
```

will do.

If there is any package not in Fink that you wish to install, make sure to [follow their advice](http://www.finkproject.org/faq/usage-general.php?phpLang=en#compile-myself) on what environment variables should be defined.  This way, you'll have less trouble compiling more recent versions of some packages, etc., in case you need them.